# GWT: conflicting classes in the gwt-user.jar

Tags: java, json, gwt

This sounds like a stupid question, but I cannot find the answer.

I'm using GWT and I need to use JSON on the client. Corresponding classes are in package *com.google.gwt.json.client* and are located in *gwt-user.jar*. However, the same JAR contains *javax.servlet* classes that conflict (different version) with the ones I use in servlet container. How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gwt-user.jar is not needed in server side, so dont deploy it in your container.

If you are using maven, set the scope of the gwt-user dependency as 'provided'.